# Highlight all subscribed sites on the "all sites" overview

Tags: feature-request, design, stack-exchange, stackexchange.com

### proposal

On the ["all sites"](https://stackexchange.com/sites) overview, it would be nice to indicate to a logged-in user which sites he/she is a member of (i.e., has an account) by visually highlighting the corresponding tiles.

### Sloppy proof-of-concept mockup screenshots:

**Highlight**

[image: Screenshot 1]

---

**Outer glow**

[image: Image 2]